# Alternative for using global to pass parameters within the project

Tags: node.js

I am a `Java` and `C#` developer. This is the first time I'm working on `NodeJS`.

I want to make available a value of a few parameters within the project. For example I want to use the `UserId` throughout the project. I use `global.username="SIA"` to save it and use the same to retrieve the parameter.

I have found out that using `global` is discouraged in `NodeJS`. So what is the workaround ?

Comment: You can define vars in standalone module `myglobal.js`, exports them e.g. `module.exports = {var1: 10, var2: ...}` and use it by `var global = require('myglobal.js');`. After `global.var1 = 11` this variable change in global also.

Answer (score 0):

Using globals is bad practice.
For example because of unit tests or reusability.

In similar situations create separate config file with settings, and then inject it to modules

Your child modules may looks:

```
module.exports = function (config, otherDependences) {
  ...
};
```

And parent components may looks:

```
var config = ...;
var otherDependences
require('./path/to/childComponent')(config, otherDependences);
```

Most of components will have both structures"

```
module.exports = function (config, otherDependences) {
  ...
  require('./path/to/childComponent')(config, otherDependences);
  ...
};
```

And build your structure hierarchically. Each component is child for some components, and parent for others. But pass only data which is required - not everything - it will simplify unit tests.